# Actionscript 3 Json?

Tags: json, flash, actionscript

Just going to say that I'm new to AS3,
What I'm trying to do is to parse json in flash and use the contents,

I've googled a lot and realized that I can't do it without a library that's called 'as3corelib',
I went for it and started trying to get it to work,

But I haven't made it to even import it and use it properly,
All I want to know is how to import it, and how to use it to read json,

I tried to read the documentation, and readme files, but I'm still lost,
I'd be grateful if you guys could help me here,
Thanks!

Comment: What IDE do you use? Flash Builder, Flash CS, etc..?

Comment: @user1113426 I'm using Flash CS3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**as3corelib** you can find from [here](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/downloads). Download latest .zip and find `lib/as3corelib.swc` file. Then by using '[How to use SWC in Flash CS3](http://www.myflashlab.com/2010/01/17/how-to-use-swc/)' link, import `as3corelib.swc` to your project. About how to use json serializing/deserializing , look at `JSON` class in `docs` which is existed in downloaded .zip as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll go on and download, have a great day

Answer (score 0):

In Flash Player 11 and Air 3, JSON became a native, built-in Object in ActionScript.  No need for external libraries.  See [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) or this [help article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS324d8efcab3b0d1e2408f9e3131fddffcfc-8000.html).

Comment: Yeah, that is true, that there is built-in support for JSON. But you can't 'persuade' `flash cs3.0 compiler` to compile `JSON.parse` like codes without including lib!!

Comment: Ah, I didn't see he specified Flash CS3.